# Intel Corporation 82579LM ubuntu 12.04 connection drops every 5 minutes

Tags: 12.04, networking

I have a problem with my new Dell Optiplex 9010, the Intel Corporation 82579LM ethernet card and ubuntu 12.04. My ethernet connection drops often (almost every 5 minutes) and then restarts after 30 seconds. I have already installed the last version of the e1000e drivers and disabled IPv6 but it did not solve my problem. Any idea on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to edit your Connection, configure different methods for authentication under connections & yeah see that you have updated & latest version drivers running.